# Close Angular Material Stepper

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular6

This may be a very simple question. How do you close the Angular Material Stepper? I want to close the box via a `mat-button,` but i did not see it in the documentation. Maybe i am blind.

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#completed-step

Comment: The stepper isn't a modal dialog.

Comment: Well dang! So i will just allow the user to click off when finished then lol.

Comment: Is there a way to call the escape key in JavaScript when running a method.

Comment: If you show the modal dialog using the MatDialog service. It always supports the escape key to close dialogs.

Comment: Yea i have used a MatDialog and really like it, i just wanted to use the stepper to make it easier on the user to enter large amounts of data needed. I wonder if you can add the stepper inside a MatDialog?

Comment: You absolutely can use the stepper inside a dialog. I think that was what it was designed for.